# Percentage of Sum of 2 Continuous distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In a factory, there are Independents 2 pipe-cutter machines.

The length of the pipes from the first machine is $X_{1}$.

The length of the pipes from the second machine is $X_{2}$.

I know that $X1\sim N(\mu = 101, \sigma^2 = 102)$ and $X_{2}\sim unif(85,115)$.

I know also that proper pipe is $\in[90,110]$ and that $\frac{9}{10}$ of all the pipes are propers.

What is the percentge of the pipes that have been cut by the first Machine ?

**My attempt**

I know that $X1\sim N(\mu = 101, \sigma^2 = 102)$, and therefore $P(90 \leq   X_{1} \leq 110) = 0.676$.
Furthermore, $X_{2}\sim unif(85,115)$ and therefore $P(90 \leq   X_{2} \leq 110) = \frac{2}{3}$.

Now I made 2 equation -

$n_1$ - the number of pipes have been cut by the first Machine.

$n_2$ - the number of pipes have been cut by the second Machine.

$n$ - The total number of pipes that have been cut.

So,

(1) $n_1 + n_2 = n$

(2) $0.676 n_1 + \frac{2}{3} n_2 = \frac{9}{10} n$

But, $n_1$ can't be negative,
Where is ny mistake ?

Thanks.

Comment: If **both** probabilities are less than $0.9$ (and if your calculation of these probabilities are okay then this is the case) then for **every** division the probability on a proper pipe will be less than $0.9$.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Exactly what I am saying. If one machine has probability $p_1<p$ to produce a proper pipe, and the other has probability $p_2<p$ to do that, then the result of a mixup of both machines cannot exceed or equalize $p$. So $p=0.9$ must be wrong or otherwise at least one of the calculations of $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Comment: I got you.
Did you find my problem in my calculations ?

Comment: I can only tell you that one of $p,p_1,p_2$ must be wrong (or else the problem cannot be solved). Further I am not willing (too lazy) to check any calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Let's check your probabilities:

If $X_1 \sim N(\mu = 100, \sigma^2 = 102),$ Then $P(90 \le X_1 \le 110) =  0.6755.$ I did the computation in R:

```
 diff(pnorm(c(90,110), 101, sqrt(102)))
 ##   0.6755299
```

Maybe it's supposed to be $\sigma^2 = 10^2.$ Then the probability
is 0.6802738, but that's not enough of a difference to cure the
fundamental problem.

[My answers from R do not involve round-off errors from standardizing
and using printed normal tables.]

Also, $P(90 \le X_2 
\le 110) = 2/3$ as you say.

```
 diff(punif(c(90,110), 85, 115))
 ## 0.6666667
```

So the Comments are correct. There is no way that a mixture
of pipes from two processes each making about 2/3 proper pipes
can give an overall fraction of 9/10 proper pipes.

The idea of this problem is sound, and it is intended to illustrate an
important principle. If you want a version of the problem that can be solved, then try using
$\sigma = 5$ for $X_1.$ With that change, about 95% of the pipes from
the 'normal' process will be good ones.